# por que a função não está se repetindo

Tags: javascript, html

Eu criei um código que gera "títulos" aleatórios, mas, não está fazendo exatamente o que eu quero, eu quero: que a cada clique em "gerar" gere um titulo novo, mas isso não está acontecendo.

```js
var i = 1
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var randColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
var g = "o titulo foi gerado pela"
var titulo = " clique para gerar o titulo"
var nomes = ["olá", "hellow", "eu aquero"]
var gerar = Math.floor((Math.random() * nomes.length)); // gerador de nomes aleátrios

document.getElementById("clique para gerar o titulo").innerHTML = titulo
const btn = document.getElementById('botao');

function clicked() {
  titulo = "o titulo gerado foi:"
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = (randColor)
  if (resultado === "red", "blue", "green", "yellow") {
    document.getElementById("clique para gerar o titulo").innerHTML = titulo
    document.getElementById("vezes").innerHTML = g + " " + i + "º" + "vez"
    console.log(g + " " + i++);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title> sortear nomes </title>
  <style>
    button {
      background: black;
      outline: none;
      border: 0;
      padding: 20px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
  <h1 id="clique para gerar o titulo"> </h1>
  <h6 id="vezes"></h6>
  <h1 resultado></h1>
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="resultado"></h1>
  <button id="botao" onClick="clicked()">Gerar</button>
```

Comment: Amigo, não consegui entender o problema. Tu poderias dar mais detalhes, explicar melhor o teu objetivo e descrever o comportamento inesperado do teu código?

Comment: Basicamente, eu quero que a cada clique em "gerar" faça um novo nome aparecer por exemplo: o nome ta red, quando eu clicar em gerar mude o nome para outro

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que o código `randColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]` que gera o novo texto não está sendo executado dentro da função, apenas uma vez.

Eu coloquei dentro da função e o nome muda quando clica agora.

```js
var i = 1;
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var g = "o titulo foi gerado pela";
var titulo = " clique para gerar o titulo";
var nomes = ["olá", "hellow", "eu aquero"];

document.getElementById("clique para gerar o titulo").innerHTML = titulo;
const btn = document.getElementById('botao');

function clicked() {
  randColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  titulo = "o titulo gerado foi:";
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = (randColor)
  if (resultado === "red", "blue", "green", "yellow") {
    document.getElementById("clique para gerar o titulo").innerHTML = titulo
    document.getElementById("vezes").innerHTML = g + " " + i + "º" + "vez"
    i++;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title> sortear nomes </title>
  <style>
    button {
      background: black;
      outline: none;
      border: 0;
      padding: 20px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
  <h1 id="clique para gerar o titulo"> </h1>
  <h6 id="vezes"></h6>
  <h1 resultado></h1>
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="resultado"></h1>
  <button id="botao" onClick="clicked()">Gerar</button>
  
 </body>
 </html>
```